# Using AD/GPO to add machines to WSUS in Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2012, wsus

I was following this guide:

http://knowledge.quickstart.com/configure-wsus-to-deploy-updates-using-group-policy/

I've rebooted the machines after the policy updates to ensure they took them. I ran an update and I get the error: 80244019.

Am I missing something? It takes the GPO but WSUS does not seem to see the machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue. Apparently, you need to add the port numbers even if you still run the default port numbers. So that must be a Windows 2012 change as that guide is Windows 2008 and does not include port numbers.

Professional note: Always use port numbers regardless.